# Postgresql search in json

Tags: json, postgresql

Foк example I have such table

```
                id                               data
0ab5203b-9157-4934-8aba-1512afb0abd0 {"title":"Board of Supervisors Meeting","id":"1i3Ytw1mw98"}
7ee33a18-63da-4432-8967-bde5a44347a0 {"title":"Board of Supervisors Meeting","id":"4-dNAg2mn6o"}
8d71ca35-74eb-4751-b635-114bf04843f1 {"title":"COPD 101", "id":"l9O0jCR-sxg"}
```

And selects

```
select * from module_data where data::json->>'title' like '%Board%' 
select * from module_data where data->>'title' like '%Board%'
```

Questions:

1. How to search for any json node? Something like

   `select * from module_data where data::json like '%Board%'`
2. JSON structure in the rows of the table can be different

I have a table audit

```
id
created
json
```

I need to find the row when the DTO object was changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PostgreSQL 10 introduces [Full Text Search on JSONB](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-textsearch.html)

```
CREATE INDEX ON module_data
    USING gin ( to_tsvector('english', data) );
```

The new FTS indexing on JSON works with phrase search and skips over both the JSON-markup and keys.